# How do I access an HTTPS router config page that still uses RC4?

Tags: networking, browser, ssl

I have an old wireless router that I haven't needed to change the configuration on for years. Recently I ran into some issues with my network and needed to turn on it's DHCP server. When I went to load the config page I found out that the web server on the router only uses an old weak SSL cipher that Chrome and IE won't access it.

Is there a way to enable RC4 in modern browsers? This router basically becomes a piece of plastic if I can't update the config.

Comment: No, RC4 has been deprecated in modern browsers. Replace the router....http://venturebeat.com/2015/09/01/google-microsoft-and-mozilla-will-drop-rc4-support-in-chrome-edge-ie-and-firefox-next-year/

Comment: [blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-web-is-world-wide-or-who-still-needs-rc4/) says "In total, roughly 0.000002% of requests to CloudFlare use the RC4 protocol."  Moab's link shows a much higher usage, noting, "Mozilla also shared that about 0.08 percent of Firefox users in the release channel still use RC4."  Since that link said Firefox 44 would drop support, your best bet may be to use Firefox 43.  Or see if there is another way to configure the router, such as via an SSH or Telnet connection.

Comment: Are you sure it's the cipher and not the protocol? My IE11/Win8.1 (though not Chrome) will connect RC4 TLS1.0 after fallback, but not SSL3 with still-strong ciphers. In any case, I would try a reverse proxy (Apache, nginx) or tamper proxy (fiddler, burp, ZAP) with no actual tampering or just transport proxy (stunnel) to take the lameo HTTPS from the router and give your browser either good HTTPS or just HTTP since I assume you don't really care about the security here.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing Firefox 5 which allowed me to connect to the router. Tonight I'll be downloading a new firmware which will hopefully fix this issue completely.